# Why am I getting "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I have a simple table called LookupTable with two fields: Id (int) and Description (nvarchar) that I want to use to populate a drop down list.

The following code gives me the error:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = 
  _entities.LookupTable.Select(t=> new SelectListItem {Value = t.Id, 
                                                       Text = t.Description } );
```

I have a using System.Linq; statement already, and I get a runtime error if I try t.Id.ToString().

I must be missing something simple, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question what is the type of `_entities.LookupTable`. If we suppose that it is some `IQueryable<SomeModel>` or `IEnumerable<SomeModel>` where `SomeModel` contains two properties `Id` and `Description`, you must ensure that you are properly converting those two values to string as the `Value` and `Text` properties of a `SelectListItem` are strings.

You may also try to eagerly execute the query by calling `.ToString()`:

```
var items = _entities
    .LookupTable
    .ToList()
    .Select(t => new SelectListItem 
    {
         Value = t.Id.ToString(), // <-- notice that you might need a ToString if the Id property is integer 
         Text = t.Description 
    });
```